# what is the unscaled value of BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I was reading the doc of BigDecimal and i didn't understand what **unscaled**  meaning. Can anyone explain to me with a example？Thanks.

Here is the context

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers. A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer **unscaled** value and a 32-bit integer scale. If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale.

Comment: So, what don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand what unscaled value mean.

Comment: Does 'unscaled' mean 'without decimal digits' and not multiplied with ten power scale?

Answer (score 13):

> A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale

```
unscaled integer value of arbitrary precision: 87866787879879879768767554645434
scale: 3
```

> If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

```
actual decimal value: 87866787879879879768767554645.434
```

> If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale.

```
unscaled integer value: 87866787879879879768767554645434
scale: -3
actual decimal value: 87866787879879879768767554645434000
```

Comment: As the number being huge isn't really important here, it may be clearer with a smaller number, like `123456`.

Comment: I wanted to emphasize that the term "integer" here must be taken in the mathematical meaning, not the Java meaning. The unscaled value is not a 32-bit Java int.

Comment: So what is a  *unscaled integer*. What's a scaled integer like ?

Comment: @ChongYoung: There is no scaled integer in this case. The *unscaled* value is an integer, the *scaled* value may or may not be an integer.

Comment: The scaled integer is the result: the decimal value. i.e. the unscaled integer to which a scale has been applied to ransform it to a decimal value. Just as a full glass is an empty glass that you have filled, or an empty glass is a full glass that you have emptied.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder : So any integer is a unscaled value?

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please add an explanation as to why 87866787879879879768767554645434 has a scale value of 3?

Comment: @QuaziIrfan It's just an example of a BigDecimal that would have such an unscaled value and such a scale. You can create such a BigDecimal using `new BigDecimal(new BigInteger("87866787879879879768767554645434"), 3);`, or simply using `new BigDecimal("87866787879879879768767554645.434");`

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. But `new BigDecimal(new BigInteger("1234"), 3)` is printing as `1.234`. Why? I understand that setting the value of scale to 3 is moving the decimal point - but that is also changing the original value 1234.

Comment: Because the first argument is not the value of the decimal. It's the unscaled value. Read the javadoc.

Comment: I'd like to see the arbitrary precision integer unscaled value just to confirm my understanding, which is that scale has no effect on precision. The value of a BigDecimal can hide precision according to the scale, but the BigDecimal still has its arbitrary precision integer unscaled value. I should be able to setScale to a greater value and see digits that had only apparently been lost.

Answer (score 6):

`BigDecimal` is an arbitrary precision integer with a 32-bit integer scale i.e [image]

For Example -

1. 878667 is an unscaled integer value having precision (count of
   significant digits) of 6. After applying the scale of 2 i.e [image] ->
   8786.67 (output). After applying scale of -2 i.e [image] -> 87866700 (output).
2. 0.0000009 is a scaled integer value with precision of 1(count of significant digits) and scale of 7 thus the unscaled value -> 9 i.e [image]